# Redirecting via a loop to single controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a page that displays a table. The tables's last column contains a string that refers to a listcode to create a list for dropdown element. The table column can contain a number of rows. The next page shows the list created from the the table page filter. The problem I have is that I need to redirect the list page back to itself for the next list. In the list page controller I delete the first row of the table so I always have a new list. I tried to redirect back to the page with a button that calls a named route. I just takes me to different page I use to start the whole process. So, how to I redirect to the same page multiple times. I would prefer to use the selected item from the list to activate the process but am unable find a method that works so I just use a button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code what you did

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I've given up this project due to lack of decent documentation for a new user. Thanks.